# ffmpeg takes a lot of time when splitting a video towards the end

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, video-encoding

I have a 3 hours long video and I am trying to split the video at given intervals. The intervals which appear earlier are quickly split but the later ones takes a lot of time. The command that I have been trying is this:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=24:min-keyint=120 -crf 19 -ss 5000 -to 5010 output.mkv`

This gives me the correct split but takes a lot of time.

I have tried adding -ss before as well to test if it works but it also takes some time to process and the clip length is much larger than 10 secs, approx 55 mins but it's not playable after 10 sec:

`ffmpeg -ss 5000 -to 5010 -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=24:min-keyint=24 -crf 19 output.mkv`

How do I make ffmpeg run faster and also get the desired duration result?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -ss 5000 -i input.mkv -t 10 ...`